type recognition template check returns wrong result
I have following piece of code.
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

typedef char stringType1;
typedef char stringType2;

typedef enum
{
    myType_noType,  // 0
    myType_stringType1, // 1
    myType_stringType2  // 2
} MyDataType_t;

//TYPE CHECK
template <typename T>
constexpr MyDataType_t TYPE_NAME(T x)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(x),stringType1>::value){return myType_stringType1;}

    if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(x),stringType2>::value){return myType_stringType2;}

    return myType_noType;
}

template <typename T>
MyDataType_t myFunction(T *value)
{
    return TYPE_NAME(*value);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World"<< std::endl;

    stringType1 var1;
    stringType2 var2;

    MyDataType_t aTypeId = myFunction(&var1);    
    std::cout << aTypeId << std::endl;
    aTypeId = myFunction(&var2);    
    std::cout << aTypeId << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Running this piece of code gives following result:
Hello World

1

1

So it looks like I have variables of different types that cannot be recognized properly during runtime.
And there is a question: is there any way we could distinguish these types as different?
Edit: I got it. So now: is there a way to recognize these type aliases during runtime?

You declared both stringType1 and stringType2 to be the same type char. Remember that typedef declares an alias for a type, not a new type.

Slight nitpick: TYPE_NAME is not a macro but a function (that is named like a macro)

"types that cannot be recognized properly during runtime...." Types are fixed at compile time in c++.

See dupe: When typedef is used in C, will it create a new type or only a type name?

"is there any way we could distinguish these types as different?..." They're the same types. It doesn't make sense to distinguish between them. It's like asking can we distinguish between int and int. The names/aliases don't actually exist. They're just for the programmer's ease.

@user12002570
But is there a way to recognize these aliases?

@Filip I've added another dupe: What is the best way to tell the compiler to differentiate between two types which hold the same kind of data
